# Multiple arguments with the same type

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse to generate CLI. There are two positional arguments which are all of type str and can occur several time (i.e., nargs='+').

What my current code looks like is :

```
    parser.add_argument('-a', type=str, nargs='+', required=True,
                        help='argument a')
    parser.add_argument('-b', type=str, nargs='+', required=True,
                        help='argument b')
```

However, this is not a good solution as both of a and b are "optional arguments" in the help document. I want to make a and b both positional.

Is there any way to do so in argparse?
Such as:

```
python main.py a=["a_1", "a_2"] b=["b_1", "b_2"]
```

Comment: "I want to make a and b both positional." - that doesn't make sense as an interface. If I execute `your_program.py a b c d e`, which of those arguments are supposed to be `a` arguments and which of those arguments are supposed to be `b` arguments?

Comment: @user2357112 that's why I'm asking.. Is there any explicit way to distinguish them?

Comment: Just make one positional argument with '+', and split the list after parsing.  You are the only one who can tell which belong to `a` and which to `b`.  We can't.

Comment: If you define two positionals with'+', the 2nd one will get the last string, and the 1st will get the rest.

Comment: Look at `sys.argv`.  That's what argparse looks at.

Answer (score 3):

`help` with your initial definition is:

```
usage: stack52580176.py [-h] -a A [A ...] -b B [B ...]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -a A [A ...]  argument a
  -b B [B ...]  argument b
```

The usage line shows that `-a` requires at least one argument; same for `-b`.

Yes, the 2 arguments are in the `optional arguments` group. The only default alternative is `positional arguments`.  There isn't a 'required' group, or 'required but flagged' group.

But replacing input like

```
python main.py -a a_1 a_2 -b b_1 b_2
```

with:

```
python main.py a=["a_1", "a_2"] b=["b_1", "b_2"]
```

will be awkward for both your users and yourself.  It'll need some extra quotes to keep the shell from splitting on all spaces.  And you'll have to parse the string 'a=["a_1", "a_2"]' yourself.

But if it's just the group name that bothers you, we can change that with an argument_group

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments:')
g.add_argument('-a', type=str, nargs='+', required=True,
                        help='argument a')
g.add_argument('-b', type=str, nargs='+', required=True,
                        help='argument b')
parser.print_help()
```

which produces:

```
usage: stack52580176.py [-h] -a A [A ...] -b B [B ...]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit

required arguments::
  -a A [A ...]  argument a
  -b B [B ...]  argument b
```

If the arguments hadn't been marked as `required`, usage would have had extra []:

```
usage: stack52580176.py [-h] [-a A [A ...]] [-b B [B ...]]
```

The possibility of specifying `required` (and '?' nargs) blurs the conventional distinction between `optionals` and `positionals`.  We can have required optionals, and optional positionals.